# jQuery - Is there a way to 'save' a state of dom elements (css) and revert to that saved state etc..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a css menu that also does child menus etc.. the problem is, I have to create eventHandlers for for tab/jaws users. It seems when I manipulate the menu(s) with show()/hide() it mucks up the inherent css selectors and their states, so if a user wanted to do both tab and mouse move - it won't work. They either have to use all mouse or tabbing etc..

I *could* create more js eventhandlers for mouseovers/outs etc..but curious if it would be feasible to clone the parent elements onload, and tie-into the tabbing that when they tabbed "off" the menu, I "revert" to this saved state so then the user can use the css method of mouseover/out etc..

Does this make sense? Or is this as much work/overhead as just creating more eventHandlers for the mouse events?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Clone the menu, remove the old menu, append the clone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of saving and restoring a menu just as you suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/5pvGG/

```
var $saved = $('#cssmenu').clone();

$('#a').click( function() {
    $('#cssmenu').remove();
});

$('#b').click( function() {
    $('body').prepend($saved);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out tomorrow, and come back to accept. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Could we possibly take this further? I've been wanting to be able to save a DOM clone, and be able to revert to it after closing and reopening the browser!

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo - I supposed if you saved the data to localstorage then you could restore the state when a user returns. Otherwise you'd have to send the structure up to your server and store it there.

Comment: @mrtsherman. Using the example right here, `$saved` is a jQuery object. The problem with your proposed solution is: data can normally be saved as text. Even if you save the `.text()` of the object, I guess you might be able to reload it, but obviously you'd lose any data and events. That'd totally kill any dynamic page.